# How to implement an action after the closure of an interstitial?

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I would implement an action when the user close an interstitial, what syntax identified that if the interstitial was closed executes such an action?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can set an `AdListener` which provides various callback methods such as `onAdFailedToLoad`, `onAdLoaded`, `onAdClosed` etc. Just override the method `onAdClosed` and the code inside it will be executed after the ad is closed.

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // do your required action.
    }

    // override other methods if required.
});
```